# Python - Multiprocessing reading files from sub directories and creating csv file list output

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm new to python.

I'm trying to read all pdf files on sub-folders and add  the name and file path of each file to a csv file. ( This part of the code works)

I would like to use multiprocesseing to read all this files faster and create the csv file output.

Can anyone give me some tips?

Thank you.

```
import os
import csv
# Right function using slice
def right(s, amount):
    return s[-amount:]

# File Directory
search_directory ="C:/Myfolder/"
# File Name for Output CSV
output_file = right(search_directory,8) +'_pdf_files_.csv'

with open(output_file, 'w',newline='') as csvfile:
    list_writer= csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for path,sub, files in os.walk(search_directory):
     for filename in files:
       if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        file_path = os.path.join(path,filename)
        file_list =[file_path, filename[5:15]]
        list_writer.writerow(file_list)
        print('Reading:'+ filename)
```

Comment: In fact the multiprocessing module might speed up your code if your code is CPU limited.
If it is io-limited I'm not sure you can gain a lot.

Also writing to one and the same csv file with one module is not that easy and might even slow down.

Can you just run your program and check how many percent of CPU your process takes.
If it takes less then 100%, then I'd guess your  code is not CPU limited and that multirpcessing will not help.

Perhaps just removing the print will already accelerate your code considerably?

Comment: As stated by @gelonida, it is not likely to help you any by adding multiprocessing to this code, as it is IO bound. Howerver, I have to ask, how many pdf-files do you have in the folder? Do you really need to run this using `multiprocessing`? Or is it to learn how to do it?

Comment: I don't need to print the filename. Definitively that would help.

Comment: @JohanL  There are around 50 - 60 thousand pdfs everyday.